# Jinja 2 For loop crashes Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have a simple test snippet of Jinja templating I was writing for HTML templating but for some reason for loops crash the online app engine and the devappserver. I've tried substituting the subject of my for loop with a constant just to test the actual looping and according to the Cloud SDK Shell error messages I've isolated it to the actual syntax of the for loop. What is wrong with the snippet?

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\Documents\Reverie\reflect\templates\index.html", 
line 9,
 in template
    {{% for test in my_list %}}
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> {{my_list[3]}} </h1>
<ul>
    {{% for test in my_list %}}
    <li>{{my_list[1]}}</li>
    {{% endfor %}}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

test.py

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    """docstring for MainPage"""
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html", title="Nani", my_list=[0,1,2,"string"])

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),], debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: test.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Full Stacktrace

```
ERROR    2017-07-18 05:02:36,960 webapp2.py:1528] unexpected '%'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\Documents\Reverie\reflect\test.py", line 22, in get
    self.render("index.html", title="Nani", my_list=[0,1,2,"string"])
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\Documents\Reverie\reflect\test.py", line 17, in render
    self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\Documents\Reverie\reflect\test.py", line 13, in render_s
tr
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 719, in get_templa
te
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 693, in _load_temp
late
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\loaders.py", line 127, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 493, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\Documents\Reverie\reflect\templates\index.html", line 9,
 in template
    {{% for test in my_list %}}
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'
ERROR    2017-07-18 05:02:36,960 wsgi.py:279]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\Documents\Reverie\reflect\test.py", line 22, in get
    self.render("index.html", title="Nani", my_list=[0,1,2,"string"])
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\Documents\Reverie\reflect\test.py", line 17, in render
    self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\Documents\Reverie\reflect\test.py", line 13, in render_s
tr
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 719, in get_templa
te
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 693, in _load_temp
late
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\loaders.py", line 127, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 493, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source)
  File "C:\Users\Skyler\Documents\Reverie\reflect\templates\index.html", line 9,
 in template
    {{% for test in my_list %}}
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'
INFO     2017-07-17 22:02:36,970 module.py:832] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because you seem to use one curly brace too much. Look at the for loop from the [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/):

`<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
  <li><a href="{{ user.url }}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>`

There is only one curly brace in the statement `{% for user in users %}` while your statement uses two curly braces: `{{% for test in my_list %}}`.

Try instead: `{% for test in my_list %}` and see what happens.

Comment: that was it, holy derp i spent so much time blind to that.

interesting that an extra brace might cause the error, any idea why that might be the case, as far as the interpreter lifecycle goes?

Comment: @Skyler I think that one must dig rather deep into the jinja2 source to find why this is the case. I agree that it should fail more gracefully.